# oracle measure execution time

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have an oracle database and some queries written as scripts in SQL. I'd like to measure execution time of each query so I found this part of code on the Internet:

```
DECLARE
  t1 NUMBER;
  t2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  t1 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
  -- MY QUERY
  t2 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(t2 - t1);
END;
```

As 'my query' I simply write:

```
@directory\script.sql
```

but it gives me an error.

> Error report: ORA-06550: linia 8, kolumna 1: PLS-00103: Encountered
>   the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:
>   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with << continue close current
>   delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute
>   commit forall merge pipe purge 06550. 00000 - "line %s, column
>   %s:\n%s" *Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. *Action:

I'm pretty new to databases and I'd like to ask for your advice. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add error text?

Comment: And the error is?  The StackOverflow spy planes are rather advanced but there are clouds blocking the view of your screen at the moment.

Comment: We at StackOverflow are usually confused with wizards mind readers... But we are not! Please tell us what was the error message....

Comment: If, as you said, you are "pretty new to databases", you may have your priorities wrong. Why are you looking to measure execution times using procedures? First learn plain SQL (there is A LOT to learn); procedures should be used as a last resort, when what you need to do can't be done in plain SQL. And, let your front-end (SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer, Toad etc.) tell you - or log - how long it took a query to execute, don't do it by hand. Spend the time where it will be used most efficiently: learn and practice good SQL code writing.

Comment: Did you replace the `-- MY QUERY` with `@directory\script.sql`? If so, you put a SQLPlus command in a PLSQL block, and this can't work.

Comment: @Aleksej It can work. SQL*Plus can expand a referenced to an external `sql` file inside a pl/sql block. But it's definitely a very inconvenient and error-prone way to do things.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov: can I ask you an example or a link? thanks

Comment: @Aleksej Sure. [Here is one](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PIpDgtJrmQoYHibMHPA5g6rs0mCHnwx9BHNbc-AoRE8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Excuse me I was in hurry and forgot to paste an error message:

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov That easy! Always so much to learn.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the execution time of your sql, simply get the SQL_ID and run the below query (it has to be in the cache when you run this. If you have the diagnostics pack, I can give you the historical version of this query to see trends).

1) Open 2 sessions to the instance
2) For session 1 - Get your session identifier
    a) select distinct sid from v$mystat
3) For session 1 - Issue the sql you wish to run

4) For session 2 - Get the sql_id of the first session
  a) select sql_id, prev_sql_id from v$session where sid = #####
where #### is the sid from (2)

If sql_id is null, then use prev_sql_id, otherwise, use the sql_id above and plug into below:

set linesize 300
column outline_sid format a8
column outline_category format a30
column sql_profile format a40
column child format 999
break on inst_id skip 1 on sql_id skip 1

select distinct
       sa.inst_id,
       sa.sql_id,
       sa.child_number child,
       sa.parsing_schema_name,
       sa.plan_hash_value "HASH",
       sa.outline_category,
       sa.sql_profile,
       sa.sql_plan_baseline,
       sa.users_executing,
       sa.executions "EXEC",
       sa.buffer_gets/decode(sa.executions, 0, 1, sa.executions) "LOG_PER",
       sa.disk_reads/decode(sa.executions, 0, 1, sa.executions) "PHY_PER",
       round((sa.elapsed_time/decode(sa.executions, 0, 1, sa.executions))/1000000, 6) "elapsedPer"
from gv$sql sa
where sa.sql_id = '&sqlid'
order by 1;